# Distinct or group by no working in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a sample data set.

```
id list_id user_id times
 2       1       8 2017-05-25 10:27:18
 4       2       8 2017-05-26 12:58:58
 6       1       8 2017-06-09 17:28:00
 7       2       8 2917-06-09 19:27:36
```

I have multiple list_id in table. i want to fetch only a single list_id on the basis of latest date. Please help me guys. I am using this query but i am not succeed.

```
 select * 
  from class_history 
 where user_id=8 
 GROUP 
  BY list_id 
 ORDER by id DESC
```

or

```
select *
   from class_history 
 where user_id=8 
 GROUP 
    BY list_id 
 ORDER by time DESC
```

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have distinct `id`'s so you won't be able to get distinct `list_id`'s, you would need to do:

```
SELECT B.* FROM
(
    select list_id,user_id ,max(times) times
    from class_history 
    where user_id=8
    group by list_id 
) A INNER JOIN class_history B USING (list_id,user_id,times);
```

Comment: An explanation for the -1 would be appreciated

Comment: i also want to fetch  my recent time. for display my recent history.

Comment: The downvote relates to your original answer.

Comment: @ka_lin working perfect but its fetch only one row whose list_id is 2.

Comment: And you want the time as well,yes?

Comment: @ka_lin yes i want also times. means all row.

Comment: tested, should be fine